# Can someone help export a variable in node.js

Tags: node.js, json

I am doing an exercise in the Eloquent Javascript book and am having trouble getting access to a variable with JSON information in an adjacent .js file.

My file structure looks like this: eloquentJs (folder)> ancestry.js, chapter5json.js

I am including a require statement at the top of my chapter5json.js file:
require("./ancestry.js");

as well as:

```
module.exports = ANCESTRY_FILE;
```

at the bottom of my ancestry.js file.

When I try to run the following code in chapter5json.js:

```
var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);
console.log(ancestry.length);
```

I get an error that the

> variable ANCESTRY_FILE is not defined.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do you declare `ANCESTRY_FILE`?

Comment: ANCESTRY_FILE is the variable inside of ancestry.js that I am trying to export to chapter5json.js

Comment: How are you importing the  ANCESTRY_FILE ?

Comment: In which file are you getting error : variable ANCESTRY_FILE is not defined.

Comment: @DeepKakkar I tried using a require at the top of my chapter5json.js file.. error is in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the require statement like this:  `let ancestor = require("./ancestry.js")`

Since the file is simply a json, simply use the `ancestor` like this:
`let ancestry = JSON.parse(ancestor);`

Now you can use all the variables using the reference of `ancestry`

Comment: JSON.parse(ancestor.ANCESTRY_FILE) gave me a JSON unexpected token u error. 
Instead I just tried JSON.parse(ancestor).. and it was able to return me the correct length I was looking for in chapter5json.js. Thanks

Comment: oh okay, so the ancestry.js is just a json file which you can get by requiring. I'll update the answer.

Comment: chapter5json.js is the file I am running the JS code from.
ancestry.js is the file with var ANCESTRY_FILE = JSON.stringify([{}]) information inside